# 2sxc CustomWebApi enable CORS

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I create my custom webapi inherited from SxcApiController,
but when I try to use this api from diferent domain I get message:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have this attributes in my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous)]
```

I call my method this way:

```
    $.ajax({  
        url: apiurl,  
        type: 'POST',
        //headers: {
        //  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        //},
        //crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',  
        data: data,  
        success: function (d) {  
            debugger;
            alert("Saved Successfully");  
        },  
        error: function (d) {  
            debugger;
            alert("Error please try again");  
        }  
    });
```

if I enable crossDomain and add header the error is changed to:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I think that SxcApiController is inherited from DNN Api Controller and also don't know how to enable CORS on DNN

What else I am missing to enable CORS for this method?

============== edit 1 ================

I added this to web.config where api is hosted:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

and now the error is:

```
401 (Unauthorized)
```

What else I am missing?

============== edit 2 : Now is OK ================

I added this attributes in my method and now is OK:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect, sounds like you got it to work + it wasn't actually a CORS issue.

Just as some additional information: in case you really want to enable CORS *with authentication* for other domains, you'll need to go deeper because in that scenario the browser will do a pre-flight to really check if it's allowed to include authentication & cookies in the request. That is something that IMHO DNN doesn't provide, and you'll have to enable it using asp.net magic - basically by either creating a special request-handler for the preflight, or using asp.net header rewrites in web.config.

Comment: Are there any examples on how to actually implement this (EnableCors) in Dnn

Comment: I think you'll have to google that, as it's a DNN issue and not a 2sxc issue. We usually enable it in the web.config, but I guess people have different preferences / methods.